# EJB injection in Servelet failed with " Resolution should not happen via injection container"

Tags: eclipse, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have one EAR file with one ejb jar and web module. EJB jar contains one stateless Ejb and local interface

```
@Stateless(name="MsgProducer")
@Local(MsgProducerLocal.class)
public class MsgProducer implements MsgProducerLocal {
 public void sendMessage{}
}
```

Now i have one servlet where I am injecting this session bean with @EJB annotation but when I deploy this EAR with both ejb jar and web.war module inside it in jboss 5.1 then it is throwing the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resolution should not happen via injection container
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.getEjbJndiName(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:640)
        at org.jboss.injection.EjbEncInjector.inject(EjbEncInjector.java:80)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.populateEnc(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:482)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment$EncListener.lifecycleEvent(TomcatDeployment.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4388)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
```

In my web.xml I am using 2.5 version of schema. Here is my sample code from servelet

```
public class MessageSenderServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB(name="MsgProducer")
    public MsgProducerLocal producer;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MessageSenderServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        producer.sendMessage();
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

}
```

I am using Eclipse 3.6, JBoss 5.1, and EJB 3.0.

Can somebody will explain me what is wrong with this code?
How can I resolve this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your Servlet in .WAR file?
Note : You should put your Servlet in .war file and your ejb in jar file. And then create an ear file.

If you are implementing only one interface then you dont have to use  @EJB(name="MsgProducer")
. You can simply say  @EJB public MsgProducerLocal producer;

As you mentioned, you have web.xml version 2.5. Please make sure that you are using the correct format of it.

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">